No chime when headlights accidently left on
2010 Silverado 1500
Normally, I drive with the headlights in AUTO mode. But when it's rainy or foggy during the day, the lights don't automatically come on, even though they're needed, so I enable manual headlight mode.

With other vehicles I've owned, such as a 2005 Mailibu, the car plays a chime/beeping sound if I accidentally leave the headlights on after turning off the car. But with my truck, there's no such sound, so I often accidentally leave the headlights on after using the vehicle.
With that said, the truck does seem to automatically turn off the headlights after a few minutes (or maybe if the battery is getting low?). So the headlights haven't drained the battery to the point where the truck won't start.
But even still, I'd prefer it if the truck played a sound when the headlights are left on and the truck is off, just for peace of mind/to avoid leaving them turned on.
Is there a way to enable a headlight chime with this model of truck? I haven't seen any options for that when cycling through the dash configurations.

Do you have an aftermarket head unit in your truck? If so, the way Chevy built their vehicles is with the chime running through the stereo system. I believe that function is lost if the head unit is replaced. The headlights are turned off by the Body Control Module (BCM) for just the reason you mentioned. Is there any reason you don't just use the "AUTO" function? I have a 2018 SIlverado, which is my third one (2000 & 2006 prior). I've always thought the auto function works pretty good, except when it's raining.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks. No, I don't have an aftermarket head unit in my truck. As mentioned in the question, I normally use auto mode. Like you, I just use the manual headlight mode when it's raining.

Which is why I didn't write it as an answer ... too obvious :o)

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It occurred to me that the interior lights don't come on either when I open the driver's side door. I played with the knobs and settings in the dash but couldn't find anything that would have disabled the automatic interior lights. I wonder if the interior lights and the headlight chime use the same open-door sensor and if that sensor is broken.

Yes, the same switch to tell when the door is open is what would tell the BCM to activate the chime as well as the interior lights.  Do the interior lights come on when you open the passenger side door? If it does, the switch on the driver side is probably at fault. If it doesn't, check your fuses.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 "Do the interior lights come on when you open the passenger side door?" No, the interior lights don't come on when the driver's or passenger-side doors are open. And, of course, the headlight chime doesn't play either when the headlights are left on and the driver's door is open. As you suggested, I checked the interior fuses, but I only found an Accessory Power Outlet #16 fuse that was blown. I replaced the fuse, which fixed one of the cigarette lighter outlets, but it had no effect on the auto-interior lights and headlight chime, as expected. https://i.sstatic.net/GpeSTKQE.jpg

I'm wondering if the BCM itself is the issue. The BCM could be why the automatic lights aren't working, either. I really don't know how you'd test it, though, other than replacing it. Could probably pick one up for cheap at a pick-a-part type junkyard.
